# no export of file with sjt.itemanalysis

Tags: sjplot

i have a little question. Normally with

```
sjt.itemanalysis(df, show.shapiro=TRUE, show.kurtosis=TRUE, factor.groups.titles = "test", file = "file.html")
```

there is the possibility to export the output to a file. But no file is created; i only get the  output in the viewer. Is this an issue after the update of the sjPlot package?

Ive done this several times before and it worked

Answer (score 0):

This was a bug introduced in one of the last updates. I fixed it now and will commit to GitHub tonight, and it should be fixed in the next official CRAN update...

You could also workaround this bug:

```
tmp <- sjt.itemanalysis(x)
tmp$file <- "myfile.html"
tmp
```

This will save the table to "myfile.html".